# What is the difference between a dSYM folder and an mSYM folder?

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, crash

I am working on an Xamarin.iOS application that is crashing when being deployed via an Ad-hoc process. As [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) by Apple, when an application crashes, a `.crash` file is generated. The document also states that, as a developer, we must keep the `dSYM` folder.

Turns out, in my case, I (only?) have a `mSYM` folder.

**Question**

What is the difference between an `MyApplicationName.App.dSYM` folder and a `MyApplicationName.App.mSYM` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .dSYM

A **dSYM** file is a "debug symbols file". It is generated when the "Strip Debug Symbols" setting is enabled in the build settings of your project.

[image]

When this setting is enabled, symbol names of your objects are removed from the resulting compiled binary (one of the many countermeasures to try and prevent would be hackers/crackers from reverse engineering your code, amongst other optimisations for binary size, etc.).

dSYM files will likely change each time your app is compiled (probably every single time due to date stamping), and have nothing to do with the project settings.

> .mSYM

mSYM means MonoSymbolArchive.It contains debug info of mono.

Edit the iPhone release configuration in the csproj file to include `<MonoSymbolArchive>True</MonoSymbolArchive>` which will generate symbol data in bin/iPhone/Release/.mSYM